# Suppose A ⊆ B. Prove that for every set C, C \ B ⊆ C \ A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two problems I'm just trying to figure out the steps to solve. I'm studying for an exam and they were suggested as good study material but I don't understand how either would be solved.

1. Suppose A ⊆ B. Prove that for every set C,  C \ B ⊆ C \ A.
2. Prove that if A ⊆ B and A ⊆ C then A ⊆ B ∩ C.

I believe you can solve both by contradiction but I get lost after a few steps.

Any advice is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: You can prove them directly. To show set inclusion $X\subseteq Y$, you show that any $x\in X$ is a member $x\in Y$. So if $x\in C\setminus B$ and $A\subseteq B$, ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in C \setminus B$, then $x \in C$ and $x \notin B$ by definition, implying that $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$ by the assumption that $A \subset B$; this proves the first statement.

If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in C$ by the assumption that $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$; but this implies by definition that $x \in B \cap C$. We have proved the second statement.

Comment: Oh thanks so much I was thinking to hard on both of these to see how simple they were! Your a life saver thank you!

Comment: @mm19 No problem no problem; I cannot take your last sentence. :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $X \subseteq Y$ by definition means for any $x \in X$, $x \in Y$. So to prove 1, you can show that for any $x$, if $x \in C \backslash B$ then $x \in C \backslash A$. So let $x \in C \backslash B$ be arbitrary. By definition, this means $x \in C$ but $x \not\in B$. But then $x \not\in A$ by assumption that $A \subseteq B$. This proves that $x \in C \backslash A$. And we are done.